# Pandas how to select top 2 values after group by?

Tags: python, pandas

I got confused with sortby or nlargest functions. Can someone show me the light please? New and learning Python with all your help.

Current Dataset:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'State':['TX','TX','TX','LA','LA','LA','LA','MO','MO'],
                   'County':['TX1','TX1','TX1','LA1','LA1','LA1','LA1','MO1','MO1'],
                   'value':[1,2,3,1,2,3,4,1,4]})
```

Desired output dataset would be like this:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'State':['TX','TX','LA','LA','MO','MO'],
                   'County':['TX1','TX1','LA1','LA1','MO1','MO1'],
                   'value':[3,2,4,3,4,1]})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than one way to do this but I think the "built-in" method to select ordinal data is most likely `nth()`. [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html).

```
import pandas as pd

>>>df
  State County  value
0    TX    TX1      1
1    TX    TX1      2
2    TX    TX1      3
3    LA    LA1      1
4    LA    LA1      2
5    LA    LA1      3
6    LA    LA1      4
7    MO    MO1      1
8    MO    MO1      4

gp = df.sort_values('value', ascending=False).groupby(['State', 'County']).nth([range(2)])

>>>gp
              value
State County
LA    LA1         4
      LA1         3
MO    MO1         4
      MO1         1
TX    TX1         3
      TX1         2
```

To get the output table that you requested, reset its index.

```
>>>gp.reset_index()
  State County  value
0    LA    LA1      4
1    LA    LA1      3
2    MO    MO1      4
3    MO    MO1      1
4    TX    TX1      3
5    TX    TX1      2
```

Answer (score 1):

There's `nlargest` as you mentioned:

```
df.groupby(['State', 'County']).value.nlargest(2).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 0):

`groupby` `tail` after `sort_values`

```
df.sort_values('value').groupby(['State','County']).tail(2)
Out[179]: 
  County State  value
7    MO1    MO      1
1    TX1    TX      2
2    TX1    TX      3
5    LA1    LA      3
6    LA1    LA      4
8    MO1    MO      4
```